# loopback access model data and emit using socketio

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using Loopback as my backend and Angularjs in frontend. The requirement is to emit data based on some interval to all the connected clients.

This is my server.js file:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');   
var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.start = function() {
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module) {
    //app.start();
    app.io = require('socket.io')(app.start());
    app.io.on('connection', function(socket){
      console.log('a user connected');
       var runs = app.models.runs;
       setInterval(function(){
          //  socket.emit('model', Model.find({limit : 500})); 
        }, 2000);

      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
      });
    });
  }

});
```

Here I'm trying to access my model and emit it, but I'm not able to figure out how to access the model data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it, seems like you already got what you want from your code, not sure what's the problem. Based on the requirement you can change your code to this and it should work:

```
var runs = app.models.runs;
setInterval(function(){
  runs.find({limit : 500})).then(function(results){
    socket.emit('model', results);
  }).catch(console.error);
}, 2000);
```

Couple of things to note here.

- Don't forget proper error handling.
- The `results` variable will be an array with 500 documents inside it. Looks huge to me and it might have bad performance. Careful about it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll change the limit.
The issue I'm facing is `runs.find({limit : 500})` returns null . I don't know where I'm doing wrong .While accessing from REST api everything works fine, but in node its returning null.

Comment: Have you tried passing a callback? `runs.find({ limit: 500 }, function (err, reuslt) { socket.emit('model', results); })`

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it is working .I'm new to node world ,so it is taking me some time to figure out things.I saw you have a great experience in node ,so could you help me out little more . My requirement is to send data based on a req object passed from client . So for differnt client the req object would be different and the data sent by server would be different. The client will emit req object only once , but the server has to send the data repeated based on received req object . What would be the best approach to implement this ?

Comment: Well, the approach you have here should be fine. Though make sure you stop the setInterval when the socket is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)